# Android Application keeps crashing [Eclipse]

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {
    TextView tv;
    Button b1;
    String answer;
    RadioButton r1,r2,r3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);        
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (r1.isChecked() == true) {
                    answer=null;

                }else if (r2.isChecked() == true){
                    answer=null;
                }else if (r3.isChecked() == true){
                    answer="correct";
                }else{
                    answer="incorrect";
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this , receiver.class);
                 i.putExtra("key" , answer);
                  startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

but the problem is that the application keeps crashing upon startup . Here's my LogCat data :

```
04-03 19:56:45.955: I/dalvikvm(620): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
04-03 19:56:45.955: W/dalvikvm(620): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 320: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-03 19:56:45.955: D/dalvikvm(620): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
04-03 19:56:45.955: I/dalvikvm(620): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
04-03 19:56:45.955: W/dalvikvm(620): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 316: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-03 19:56:45.955: D/dalvikvm(620): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
04-03 19:56:45.965: D/dalvikvm(620): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
04-03 19:56:45.965: D/dalvikvm(620): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
04-03 19:56:46.115: E/FragmentManager(620): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.radiogroup:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4a312d58 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-03 19:56:46.115: E/FragmentManager(620): Activity state:
04-03 19:56:46.115: D/FragmentManager(620):   Local FragmentActivity 4a2f4a18 State:
04-03 19:56:46.115: D/FragmentManager(620):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
04-03 19:56:46.115: D/FragmentManager(620):     mLoadersStarted=false
04-03 19:56:46.115: D/FragmentManager(620):   Active Fragments in 4a2f59e8:
04-03 19:56:46.125: D/FragmentManager(620):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{4a312d58 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-03 19:56:46.125: D/FragmentManager(620):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
04-03 19:56:46.125: D/FragmentManager(620):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
04-03 19:56:46.125: D/FragmentManager(620):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
04-03 19:56:46.125: D/FragmentManager(620):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
04-03 19:56:46.125: D/FragmentManager(620):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
04-03 19:56:46.136: D/FragmentManager(620):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{4a2f59e8 in MainActivity{4a2f4a18}}
04-03 19:56:46.136: D/FragmentManager(620):       mActivity=com.example.radiogroup.MainActivity@4a2f4a18
04-03 19:56:46.136: D/FragmentManager(620):   Added Fragments:
04-03 19:56:46.136: D/FragmentManager(620):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{4a312d58 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-03 19:56:46.136: D/FragmentManager(620):   FragmentManager misc state:
04-03 19:56:46.136: D/FragmentManager(620):     mActivity=com.example.radiogroup.MainActivity@4a2f4a18
04-03 19:56:46.145: D/FragmentManager(620):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@4a2f62f0
04-03 19:56:46.145: D/FragmentManager(620):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
04-03 19:56:46.145: D/FragmentManager(620):   View Hierarchy:
04-03 19:56:46.145: D/FragmentManager(620):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4a2f9580 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.145: D/FragmentManager(620):       android.widget.FrameLayout{4a2f9ec0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.145: D/FragmentManager(620):         android.widget.LinearLayout{4a2fabe0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.155: D/FragmentManager(620):           android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{4a2fb678 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001b app:id/action_bar_container}
04-03 19:56:46.155: D/FragmentManager(620):             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView{4a304040 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001c app:id/action_bar}
04-03 19:56:46.155: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.LinearLayout{4a308948 G.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.155: D/FragmentManager(620):                 android.widget.ImageView{4a309298 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050021 app:id/up}
04-03 19:56:46.155: D/FragmentManager(620):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{4a3094c8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.155: D/FragmentManager(620):                   android.widget.TextView{4a309948 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050022 app:id/action_bar_title}
04-03 19:56:46.165: D/FragmentManager(620):                   android.widget.TextView{4a30ab88 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050023 app:id/action_bar_subtitle}
04-03 19:56:46.165: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{4a304f38 VFE...C. ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.165: D/FragmentManager(620):                 android.widget.ImageView{4a307238 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050021 app:id/up}
04-03 19:56:46.165: D/FragmentManager(620):                 android.widget.ImageView{4a307798 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050014 app:id/home}
04-03 19:56:46.165: D/FragmentManager(620):             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{4a30b558 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001d app:id/action_context_bar}
04-03 19:56:46.175: D/FragmentManager(620):           android.widget.FrameLayout{4a30bef0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
04-03 19:56:46.175: D/FragmentManager(620):             android.widget.RelativeLayout{4a30d508 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-03 19:56:46.175: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.RadioGroup{4a30dc08 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003d app:id/radioGroup1}
04-03 19:56:46.175: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.TextView{4a30e108 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003e app:id/textView1}
04-03 19:56:46.175: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.Button{4a30e878 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003f app:id/button1}
04-03 19:56:46.175: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.RadioButton{4a30f470 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050040 app:id/radioButton1}
04-03 19:56:46.185: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.RadioButton{4a310170 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050041 app:id/radioButton2}
04-03 19:56:46.185: D/FragmentManager(620):               android.widget.RadioButton{4a310b10 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050042 app:id/radioButton3}
04-03 19:56:46.185: D/FragmentManager(620):           android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{4a30c198 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001e app:id/split_action_bar}
04-03 19:56:46.185: D/AndroidRuntime(620): Shutting down VM
04-03 19:56:46.185: W/dalvikvm(620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.radiogroup/com.example.radiogroup.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.radiogroup:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4a312d58 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.radiogroup:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4a312d58 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
04-03 19:56:46.196: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  ... 11 more
```

So what is the possible reason of this error ? And thanks in advance . I apologize for my weak language .

Update : fragment_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.radiogroup.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Which Vitamin helps clotting the blood ?"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your fragment_main xml

Comment: I think that showing your layout files would help people in understanding the bug.

Comment: I've added it just now to the main post. Thanks for this tip

Comment: Could you post the rest of your MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've changed `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main)` but there's still the template-generated `PlaceholderFragment` transaction that attempts to put the fragment in view `R.id.container` in the main activity layout and the view is not found.

Either remove the transaction, or use fragment layouts the way the template wants you to: separate activity and fragment layouts and setting up listeners etc. in fragment `onCreateView()`. See [NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate)
 for more on that.