# NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

*This is a canonical question for a problem frequently posted on StackOverflow.*

I'm following a tutorial. I've created a new activity using a wizard. I get `NullPointerException` when attempting to call a method on `View`s obtained with `findViewById()` in my activity `onCreate()`.

Activity `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View something = findViewById(R.id.something);
    something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... }); // NPE HERE

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Layout XML (`fragment_main.xml`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="packagename.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/something" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The tutorial is probably outdated, attempting to create an activity-based UI instead of the fragment-based UI preferred by wizard-generated code.

The view is in the fragment layout (`fragment_main.xml`)  and not in the activity layout (`activity_main.xml`). `onCreate()` is too early in the lifecycle to find it in the activity view hierarchy, and a `null` is returned. Invoking a method on `null` causes the NPE.

The preferred solution is to move the code to the fragment `onCreateView()`, calling `findViewById()` on the inflated fragment layout `rootView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
      false);

  View something = rootView.findViewById(R.id.something); // not activity findViewById()
  something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });

  return rootView;
}
```

As a side note, the fragment layout will eventually be a part of the activity view hierarchy and discoverable with activity `findViewById()` but only after the fragment transaction has been run. Pending fragment transactions get executed in `super.onStart()` after `onCreate()`.

Comment: findViewById part should be in onActivityCreated.

Comment: @Nepster It can be but does not have to.

Comment: Sometime the activity is not yet attach to fragment.

Comment: @Nepster And that's why calling `findViewById()` on `rootView` and not on activity.

Answer (score 11):

Try **`OnStart()`** method and just use

```
View view = getView().findViewById(R.id.something);
```

or Declare any View using `getView().findViewById` method in **`onStart()`**

Declare click listener on view by `anyView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: For me this was useful because I was trying to access a sibling view inside a fragment's onCreateView, where the fragment was declared in xml. The sibling views were still null in onCreateView because the parent hadn't finished inflating, but in onStart they had :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to shift your accessing views to the onViewCreated method of fragment because sometimes when you try to access the views in onCreate method they are not rendered at the time resulting null pointer exception.

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     View something = findViewById(R.id.something);
     something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... }); // NPE HERE

     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, this is a typical error because people often don't really understand how Fragments work when they begin working on Android development. To alleviate confusion, I created a simple example code that I originally posted on [Application is stopped in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526296/application-is-stopped-in-android-emulator/24527201#24527201) , but I posted it here as well.

An example is the following:

```
public class ContainerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ExampleFragment.Callback
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
        if (saveInstanceState == null)
        {               
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.activity_container_container, new ExampleFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener()
        {
            public void onBackStackChanged()
            {
                int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                if (backCount == 0)
                {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void exampleFragmentCallback()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

activity_container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_container_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ExampleFragment:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public static interface Callback
    {
        void exampleFragmentCallback();
    }

    private Button btnOne;
    private Button btnTwo;
    private Button btnThree;

    private Callback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            this.callback = (Callback) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Activity must implement Callback interface.", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);

        btnOne = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.example_button_one);
        btnTwo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.example_button_two);
        btnThree = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.example_button_three);

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnThree.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (btnOne == v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "One.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (btnTwo == v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Two.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (btnThree == v)
        {
            callback.exampleFragmentCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/example_button_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/hello" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/example_button_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/example_button_one"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/example_button_one"
            android:layout_below="@+id/example_button_one"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/example_button_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/example_button_two"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/example_button_two"
            android:layout_below="@+id/example_button_two"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And that should be a valid example, it shows how you can use an Activity to display a Fragment, and handle events in that Fragment. And also how to communicate with the containing Activity.

Comment: This example uses the android-support-v4 library for FragmentActivity and the support fragment manager.

Comment: an even more complete example is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr

Comment: Although you should use `Otto` for communication instead of callbacks, and use `Butterknife` to inject views.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access UI elements in the `onCreate()` but , it is too early to access them , since in fragment views can be created in `onCreateView()` method. 
And `onActivityCreated()` method is reliable to handle any actions on them, since activity is fully loaded in this state.

Answer (score 2):

The view "something" is in fragment and not in activity, so instead of accessing it in activity you must access it in the fragment class like

**In PlaceholderFragment.class**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
  false);

View something = root .findViewById(R.id.something);
something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });

return root;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your **activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/myFragment"
    android:name="packagename.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared your View in the `fragment_main.xml`,move that piece of code where you get the NPE in the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment.
This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in the posted code above in the question there is a problem :
you are using R.layout.activity_main in oncreate method, but the xml files name is "fragment_main.xml" , means you are trying to get the view of fragment_main.xml file which is not being shown so it gives null pointer exception. change the code like :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);// your xml layout ,where the views are

    View something = findViewById(R.id.something);
    something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... }); // NPE HERE

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same `NullPointerException` initializing a listener after calling `findViewById()` `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` methods.

But when I've used the `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}` it works. So, I could access the `GroupView` and set my listener.

I hope it be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember important thing is :
NullPointerException occurs when you have declared your variable and trying to retreive its value before assigning value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **onViewCreated()** Method whenever using or calling views from fragments.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      View v = view.findViewById(R.id.whatever)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most popular library for finding views which is used by almost every developer.

[ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

As I can their are enough answers explaining finding views with proper methodology. But if you are android developer and code frequently on daily basis then you can use butter-knife which saves a lot time in finding views and you don't have write code for it, With in 2-3 steps you can find views in milliseconds.

**Add dependency in app level gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

**Add plugin for butter knife:**

```
File -> Settings -> plugins->
```

Then search for **Android ButterKnife Zelezny** and install plugin and restart your studio and you are done with it.

Now just go to Oncreate method of your activity and right click on your layout_name and tap on generate button and select butterknife injection option and your views references will be automatically created like mention below:

```
    @BindView(R.id.rv_featured_artist)
    ViewPager rvFeaturedArtist;
    @BindView(R.id.indicator)
    PageIndicator indicator;
    @BindView(R.id.rv_artist)
    RecyclerView rvArtist;
    @BindView(R.id.nsv)
    NestedScrollingView nsv;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_filter)
    Button btnFilter;
```