# Android WebView loadURL crashing app?

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebView siteViewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if(siteViewer != null)
        siteViewer.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();


    }
}
```

It's the default android app code, except:

```
    WebView siteViewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if(siteViewer != null)
        siteViewer.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");
```

`siteViewer` is always `null`. If I don't use the `if()` statement, the app will crash immediately upon opening, otherwise it just skips `loadURL`.

I found a similar bug here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11533

Apparently some OS's don't allow it? I'm running it on 4.4.2 in an emulator. I also tried it on a Motorola Razr with 4.1.2 and I get the same result

---

With the line `if(siteViewer != null)` commented out, this is the logcat:

```
05-15 16:05:35.112: D/AndroidRuntime(1201): Shutting down VM
05-15 16:05:35.112: W/dalvikvm(1201): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xada41ba8)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): Process: com.example.webviewtest, PID: 1201
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webviewtest/com.example.webviewtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at com.example.webviewtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-15 16:05:35.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1201):     ... 11 more
```

Here is `activity_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.webviewtest.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Here is `fragment_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.webviewtest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Following the suggestion given, this is the PlaceHolderFragment code, with the WebView code included, that gives me the error `cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity`:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        WebView siteViewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if(siteViewer != null)
            siteViewer.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to the with the bug you mention (in their case the loadUrl is executed but crashes while in your case the loadUrl won't happen because the view is null). Could you post the xml layout (activity_main.xml)?

Comment: Can you post a logcat with a crash as well

Comment: I actually used `fragment_main.xml`. Should I move it to `activity_main.xml`? The logcat reports `05-15 15:56:49.880: E/AndroidRuntime(821): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Why did I get two negative votes? This is a real problem and well documented. I can add more documentation if wanted.

Comment: It must be a joke or something as someone else downvoted it.

Comment: Call findViewById on the rootView.

Comment: I don't know if I can write this comment here, but no other question with the same general topic could answer this, but this did, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Even I am getting such error in few devices. I am not sure what is causing `WebView` to be null. I will add some screenies if my company allows it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Activity you are inflating main_layout which doesn't contain a WebView at all. Therefore the findViewById won't find anything and siteViewer is null.

Move your code to load the Url into your fragment.
Since you'r using a PlaceHolderFragment I guess it will be replaced by a real one later. That's the place to put your code. You'll probably inflate your fragment_main.xml in the fragments onCreateView and then you can load the Url in the fragment's onResume method.

To find the WebView do the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    WebView siteViewer = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    if(siteViewer != null)
        siteViewer.loadUrl("http://www.website.com");

    return rootView;
}
```

Note the rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView) instead of the simple findViewById(R.id.webView). Fragments don't have a findViewById method but since you'r inflating the layout yourself you can use the View.findViewById.

Comment: `PlaceHolderFragment` is `static`. Should I change it? I can't use `findViewById` in a static function.

Comment: 1) there are no functions in Java but methods, 2) PlaceHolderFragment is a class and the static means it's a static nested class meaning it's part of the Activity's code but still a class of its own (it can "live" outside the Activity as well unlike inner classes <- without the static). All non-static methods of PlaceHolderFragment are normal methods and you can call findViewById from there.

Comment: I put it in the method `public View onCreateView` (not static), which is a method of the `PlaceholderFragment` (static) class. It tells me `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity`

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong but since you didn't post the Fragment code I can't tell you what is wrong. If you follow the question mentioned above (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23653778/534471) it will work.

Comment: I updated it. I'm new to JAVA, but have experience in php and c++ among others. I'm looking at that question now.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect your problem with retrieving the WebView in the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

`siteViewer` is `null`, because there is no such element with id = `webView` found at the `activity_main.xml`. Please double check that you've typed it correctly.

Comment: I typed it correctly. I just did it again, both times I selected it from the list the Eclipse provides.

Comment: @JVE999 in such a case post `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I will answer from my knowledge since i didnt know the project heirarchy ...

I) .suppose you have the activity in  `package com.another.package` and your project package which is declared in the manifest is `com.main.package` now if you will try to access the webview using `R.id.webView` in package `com.another.package` it wont be available hence you will get null pointer exception so to fix that import com.main.package.R.*; in the crashing activity.

II). suppose the crashing activity is in the same package `com.main.package` then plz cross check dat whether webview named `webView` is present in the `activity_main`.

III). may be u are casting other layout to webView like `webView` is id of other than webview ( but in this case you wont get null pointer exception just for info).

Hope it helps ... Thx

Answer (score 0):

did you set the permission to access the internet in manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: it doesn't matter, the root cause is that view is not found