# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am just taking baby steps in learning Android programming..I am following some tutorials for that and while studying how to implement onKeyListener I am getting an error 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException'. This error is leading to another error 'adt unfortunately app has stopped' while trying to run the app on my phone. Here is the logcat:

```
05-15 15:55:22.087: D/AndroidRuntime(20672): Shutting down VM
05-15 15:55:22.087: W/dalvikvm(20672): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ea1ba8)
05-15 15:55:22.087: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 15:55:22.087: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): Process: com.example.keyboardlistener, PID: 20672
05-15 15:55:22.087: E/AndroidRuntime(20672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.keyboardlistener/com.example.keyboardlistener.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks all for the replies..Here is my current code:

Activity_Main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.keyboardlistener.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Fragment_Main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.keyboardlistener.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserEntry1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextResults"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextResults"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main class:
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            
            
            /*
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }*/
            
         
            final EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserEntry1);
            final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextResults);
            
            ed.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
    tv.setText(ed.getText());
    }
    }
    return false;
    }
             
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                
                return rootView;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks all for the replies..I tried removing the savedinstancestate code..but its not helping..here is the modified code from MainActivity.java

Comment: Can you put your XML Layout?

Comment: Updated the main post with all the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Check the logcat to see what line causes the NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
    at com.example.keyboardlistener.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
```

You're calling `findViewById()` too early when initializing `MainActivity` member variables. The activity doesn't have a `Window` yet.

Move the initialization to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`. There will be a `Window` at `onCreate()` phase (no NPE like this) and assuming the views are in the layout you set with `setContentView()`, you can actually find something after `setContentView()`. In case the views are in the fragment layout, move the initialization to fragment `onCreateView()` instead (See [NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate) for more on that.)

Comment: if i move the code to onCreateView in PlaceholderFragment..i am getting an error..'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById'

Comment: call it on the inflated fragment `rootView` e.g. `rootView.findViewById(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

It looks like you're using `Fragment`s here, which means that all actions that touch the UI should be done within the `Fragment`.

calling `FragmentManager.beginTransaction()` is an asynchronous task, which means by the time it finishes its not guaranteed that the `Fragment` will have been inflated or not, and so its likely that `ed` is null, causing `ed.setOnKeyListener()` to throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I have updated the root comment with modified code..its still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

quit this code

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Because you are implementing a fragment so, you can find in yout view the gui components in your main layout because your fragment is in top.

Comment: I have updated the root comment with modified code..its still not working for me