# NPE when trying to dynamically add button to android activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to add a `Button` in the `onCreate` method for an activity and am getting a Null Pointer exception; below is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // dynamic content
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("test");

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout_main);
        ll.addView(b);
    }
```

Logcat:

```
05-19 18:42:54.658: D/AndroidRuntime(2338): Shutting down VM
05-19 18:42:54.658: W/dalvikvm(2338): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a67ba8)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): Process: net.test.Rem, PID: 2338
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.test.Rem/net.test.Rem.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at net.test.Rem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-19 18:42:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(2338):     ... 11 more
```

Line 36 is `ll.addView(b);`

I read elsewhere on SO that this is because the `setContentView` is not being called before `LinearLayout`; but it seems to be, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is `linlayout_main` in `activity_main`? If so, post your logcat output. The way it looks is correct.

Comment: Nope. Right now it is looking in the wrong layout

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @josten. I don't care it's an NPE, you got to the line of code, you work backwards and you discover why it's null, then you test for null or make sure it's never null. Only other option is to keep a question and answer for every possible scenario, which among other things, would be self defeating.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate - the last paragraph also mentions why it works for you in `onStart()`

Comment: @Josten we seem to be at cross purposes. I interpreted your question as I have an NPE please help. You seem to have meant how do I make this badly designed component work. Might be worth bearing in mind we get a lot of NPE questions, so de-emphasising that aspect of the problem would be wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by dynamically adding content within `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // dynamic content
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("test");

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout_main);
    System.out.println(ll);
    ll.addView(b);
}
```

According to `onCreate()` docs:

`Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc.`

According to `onStart()` docs:

`Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.`

Based on this I moved my dynamic code to `onStart()` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is null due to layout id was not found in your current layout added i your `setContentView`

**solution::**

add a linear layout inside your `R.layout.activity_main` with the id of `linlayout_main`