# Android app crashes when showing/hiding visiblity of ImageView

Tags: android, if-statement, crash, android-imageview

I've been trying to create my first android app, and yes... got stuck up with an app crash...

I had two ImageViews in my fragment (main), overlapping imageview 1 with imageview2 in a relative layout. What I wanted to do was, *imageview1 (not imageview 2) should be showing up if there's an Internet connection. and vice versa if no internet connection.* As per a tutorial, **i created a separate class for detecting connection:**

```
   package com.mypackage.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

And called up the class in my mainactivity.class, made an if statement for two instances of connection (connected/disconnected) with a boolean variable... finally, i used setVisibility() for each ImageViews in the if statement in onCreate(). here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    } 
    Intent cd = getIntent();
    ConnectionDetector cdr = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    boolean isInternetPresent = cdr.isConnectingToInternet();
    ImageView glss2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.glass2);
    ImageView glss1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glass1);
    if (isInternetPresent) {
        glss1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        glss2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
       glss1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       glss2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you want my **layout file**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeatlinen"
tools:context="com.mypackage.myapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/glass1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/glass" android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/glass2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/glass1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:src="@drawable/broken" />
```

Everytime, when I run the program in my tablet, it crashes at the activity. i tried removing the connection detector and if statement thing, the activity moves well.

**Edit: the only problem is on the *setVisiblity()* in the if statement, because when removing it, everything else works properly. Is it possible to solve? or can we controll the visiblity of two imageviews with a different method?.**

logcat:

```
05-21 11:05:38.432: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.462: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.482: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.652: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:38.802: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(23435): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-21 11:05:38.812: D/memalloc(23435): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x50c32000 size:11960320 offset:10485760 fd:54
05-21 11:05:39.122: D/memalloc(23435): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51a3b000 size:13434880 offset:11960320 fd:57
05-21 11:05:41.542: E/filePathInTheme(23435): fallback to res
05-21 11:05:41.572: W/dalvikvm(23435): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a659f0)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lemonaade.watchr/com.lemonaade.watchr.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4450)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at com.lemonaade.watchr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1925)
05-21 11:05:41.582: E/AndroidRuntime(23435):    ... 11 more
```

thanks.

Comment: I have shortlisted my problem, and i uploaded my logcat too.

Answer (score 1):

You should move

```
ImageView glss1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glass1);
ImageView glss2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.glass2);
```

under `onCrete(....)` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 1):

please move this code below `setContentView().`

```
ImageView glss1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glass1);
ImageView glss2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.glass2);
```

You are finding view before you set the content of the view. thats why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since the layout is your fragment layout and not activity layout, the solution from a couple of other answers of moving the `findViewById()` to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()` still won't work.

Instead, move the code to the `PlaceholderFragment` `onCreateView()`, using `getActivity()` for `Context` and calling `rootView.findViewById()` on the inflated `rootView` layout.

See [NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate)
 for more.

Comment: it's not by default, present on my code (onCreateView()...) so should i add it? if so, can i do it below onCreate? edit:i found it in placeholder fragment

Comment: Looks like the code is generated from a template and the template/wizard generated PlaceholderFragment onCreateView(), too.

Comment: but eclipse says cannot make static refrence to non static method for ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());, and two findViewById()...`

Comment: In a fragment, use `getActivity()` for a `Context` and call `findViewById()` on the inflated `rootView`.

Comment: got the getActivity() right, but i've already placed the findViewById() after View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
     false);

Answer (score 0):

Write the code to the fragment `onCreateView()` of `PlaceholderFragment()` after inflating your xml .

```
ImageView glss1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glass1);
ImageView glss2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.glass2);
```

Make sure you have added Following Permission in your Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```