# Nullpointerexception thrown when trying to findViewById

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-framelayout

I have the following Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new StartFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

I get a NPE when I try to invoke `findViewByID` for `R.id.loginButton`, and I'm guessing this is because `loginButton` is within a separate Fragment, which I have as:

```
public static class StartFragment extends Fragment {

    public StartFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    }
}
```

However, I am unsure of how to fix this so that I can find the loginButton ID. I haven't worked with fragments before, so I realize I may be using them/implementing them incorrectly. `fragment_main` contains a few buttons in a `LinearLayout`, and `activity_main` has nothing but a single `FrameLayout`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Write code to initialize button from fragment becuase your button is into fragment layout not into activity's layout.*

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
    Button login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

And remove the login button related code from `onCreate` of `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement your `onCreateView(...)` in `Fragment` like

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
  false);

 View something = rootView.findViewById(R.id.something);
 something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });

return rootView;
}
```

The `Button` is in the fragment layout (`fragment_main.xml`) and not in the activity layout (`activity_main.xml`). `onCreate()` is too early in the lifecycle to find it in the activity view hierarchy, and a `null` is returned. Invoking a method on `null` causes the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` works with reference to a root view.
Without having a view in the first place will throw a null pointer exception

In any activity you set a view by calling `setContentView(someView);`.
Thus when you call `findViewById()` , its with reference to the `someView`.
Also findViewById() finds the id only if its in that `someView`. So in you case null pointer exception

For fragments, adapters, activity, .... any view's `findViewById()` will only find if the id exixts in the view
Alternately if you are inflating a view, then you can also use `inflatedView.findViewById()` to get a view from that `inflatedView`

In short make sure you have the `id` in your layout you are referring to or make `findViewById()` call in appropriate place(Ex. adapters `getView()`, activity's `onCreate()` or `onResume()` or `onPause()` , fragments `onCreateView()`, ....)

Also have an idea about UI & background thread's as you cannot efficiently update UI in bg-threads