# ListView can't be populated with an adaptor that uses HashMap filled with JSON object

Tags: android, json, listview, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

I seem not to be able to load a JSON object into a ListView. When the code reaches the line 
list.setAdaptor(..) I get an InvocationTargetException.

Step by step debugging I think the JSON object is initialized perfectly fine. The HashMap is filled correctly. I think the problem is with my ArrayAdaptor but I don't know what is going wrong.

I'm new to Android and this is my first time dealing with Adaptors and AsyncTask and JSON.
So I will be so thankful for any help. Even if you think you are stating the obvious please don't hesitate to mention whatever it is you think I am approaching the wrong way.

Here is the code to my child activity in which I am trying to populate the ListView using the JSONObject:

(if you think any other part of the code is needed please comment. I will add it right away)

```
    public class SearchResultListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    // for json
        private ProgressDialog progress;
        ListView list;
        TextView ver;
        TextView name;
        TextView api;
        Button Btngetdata;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //URL to get JSON Array
        private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";
        //JSON Node Names
        private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
        private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_API = "api";
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result_list);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         //zzz commented for let json run. uncomment when remove json   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        new JSONParse().execute();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_result_list, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View textView, int rowNumber, long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PropertyDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result_list, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    // This is the custom adapter class where you will manage the behavior of your ListView content
    public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        Context context; 
        int layoutResourceId; // This is the layout you created for the list items   
        String data[] = null; // the array with the data to populate the listview
        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();    
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtTitle);
            txtTitle.setText(data[position]);
            return row;
        }
    }
  //*********************************** inner class
    public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtTitle);
            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody1);
            api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody2);
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            //pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " 2000 "+json.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
                jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String api = c.getString(TAG_API);
                    //Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_API, api);
                    oslist.add(map);
                }
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( getApplicationContext() , oslist, R.layout.list_view_items, new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                    //R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtTitle,
                R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody1, R.id.listViewSearchResultTxtBody2});
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResult);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void showProgressDialog(final String msg) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (progress == null || !progress.isShowing()) {
                        progress = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "", msg);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        public void hideProgressDialog() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (progress.isShowing())
                            progress.dismiss();
                    } 
                    catch (Throwable e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    //json end

}
```

Here is the LogCat error. (when I debug I get InvocationTargetException, and LogCat gives me NullPointerException. I don't now why they differ :S)

```
    6-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681): Process: com.****, PID: 5681
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at com...SearchResultListActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(SearchResultListActivity.java:162)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at com..SearchResultListActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(SearchResultListActivity.java:1)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-03 08:11:56.412: E/AndroidRuntime(5681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

fragment_search_result_list.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com..SearchResultListActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewSearchResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_search_result_list.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com..SearchResultListActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

Comment: post `activity_search_result_list.xml`

Comment: @Tina have you ever heard about custom ListView with BaseAdapter?

Comment: Is the posted xml the one of Activity or Fragment. It looks like listview is in Fragment not in Activity layout. the listview initialization fails. Its null and when you set adapter to it you get NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView belongs to the Fragment Layout while you initialize it in AsyncTask invoked from Activity's `onCreate`.

You either initialize listview in Fragment or set the fragment layout to the Activity.

I would suggest you initialize listview in Fragment. To get the context use `getActivity()`.

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result_list, container, false);
        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResult);
          new JSONParse(getActivity()).execute(); 
        return rootView;
    }
```

Then

```
   Context mContext;  
   public JSONParse(Context context)
   {
       mContext= context;
   }
```

Then

```
  new SimpleAdapter(mContext...
```

Do Read

[NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate)

Comment: Before adding this JSON I had tested my ListView in the same place with some test data. It worked perfect. Are u sure I have to move it to my Fragment class?

Comment: @Tina yes.if you have a new problem post the new stacktrace

Comment: @Tina so what happens now?

Comment: what is that happens if you can post the same in your question we can help further. If you don't say what happens difficult to help further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55004/discussion-between-tina-and-raghunandan).

Comment: what happens is it's working! I just pulled out the fragment and did what u suggested in the fragment. thanks you guys.