# onCreate Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, xml

I don't understand why this code does not running:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_matchpage);

    SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);
            sb1.setEnabled(false);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

sb1 will be null.
Why?

Comment: `seek1` is not in `activity_matchpage` layout. Probably it's in the fragment layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Comment: do you have component with id seek1? Also what error do you get?

Comment: no, seek1 is in matchpage.

Comment: when I run this code in button click, it runs: SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);
            sb1.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Sow your xml code for matchpage

Comment: very long page, so this is the only seekbar <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek1" android:max="10" android:progress="5" android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
 android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: **"sb1 will be null. Why?"** : There is only one possible reason why sb1 is null and that is, quite simply, `findViewById(R.id.seek1)` is unable to find a view in your current content view with that resource id. First, try using Clean to rebuild your project then try running your app again. If you still have a problem then post your logcat (which you should have done in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely are using a `Fragment`. You should have in your code a class called `PlaceHolderFragment`, that has an `onCreateView` method.

In that project you have two xml layout, one named `activity_matchpage` and other for the fragment, `fragment_main`. You need to modify the latter and keep the first like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="youor.packaque.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

And in `fragment_main`, you declare your Views.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tformacion.finale.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <!-- Your Views here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your Java code, in `PlaceHolderFragment`, inside of `onCreateView`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        seekBar = (seekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourSeekBarId);

    }
```

If you want to get rid of the fragment you simply create your XML in `activity_matchpage` and do not add the fragment, so, remove this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: findViewById method can not called from onCreateView(). "Cannot make a static referance to the non static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity."

Comment: You need to calle it from `rootView `, `rootView.findViewById`

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer one thing from my experience that the error is coming in `SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);` but what i have noticed android compiles code from bottom so it might happen that the reason is above or somewhere else so what i will suggest replace the code in this manner :-

1. ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_matchpage);
   }
   ```
2. then if it executes then just add `SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek1);` below `setContentview`

its bit big but since you didnt provided the xml and we cant figure out if its package issue or something else so i tried to go really primitive and fundamental...

hope it helps.