# Android: Code works only in onCreateOptionsMenu, not in OnCreate

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My App works only in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method but not in `OnCreate()`.

Why?

Here it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


Button button2;

TextView joke;

Random ran = new Random();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);

    joke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joke);



    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= 49; i++)
                al.add(i);

            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                int y = al.remove(ran.nextInt(al.size()) );
                sb.append("  " + y + "  ");

            }

            joke.setText(sb);
        }
    });

    return true;
}



/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

So try to Cut & Paste the code inside `onCreate()` method... you will see the error :(

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure you have the ids - `b1` and `b2` in the layout `activity_main`?

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is invoked after the fragment transaction has been executed (in `onStart()`) and the fragment layout has become part of the activity view hierarchy. `onCreate()` is too early to find fragment views in the activity hierarchy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Comment: @GauravBhor | No, there are only on fragment_main...
The activity_main is like this:
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.etking.winningnumbersgenerator.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Answer (score 1):

You should write your code in `onCreateView` (`PlaceholderFragment` class):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        //...
        return rootView;
    }
```