# Calling javascript function from android native code

Tags: android

I have a app which goes front and back with android and js coding. Here there is a fragments which loads a html file with js file when a button is clicked using web view. There is a button in the html page.When that button is clicked , its relative js function  will be clicked. Now i wanted to call the same function on pressing of back button . How to do it?

Comment: The back button coding is in android native code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Javascript function is `myFunction()`, you have to override `onBackButton()` in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction()");
}
```

Comment: i know that, but the html page was loaded in different fragment , but i have to load function in activity so for this myWebView - how to give the reference.

Comment: take a look at [How to access Fragment's child views inside fragment's parent Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188050/how-to-access-fragments-child-views-inside-fragments-parent-activity)