# Switch findViewById returns null

Tags: android, bluetooth, findviewbyid

I am trying 2 days to solve this problem. I made a fragment in which I made a switch to enable and disable bluetooth. Well in my main activity i wrote:

```
bluetoothSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_switch);
bluetoothSwitch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
```

where clicked:

```
clicked = new ButtonClicked();
```

and:

```
class ButtonClicked implements AdapterView.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.bluetooth_switch:
                if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    Log.d("Log", "Bluetooth is disabled");
                }
                else{
                    bluetoothAdapter.enable();
                    Log.d("Log", "Bluetooth is enabled");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                startSearching();
                break;
            case R.id.discoverable_switch:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it the findViewById return null...Do you have any idea???

Comment: Where exactly is `R.id.bluetooth_switch` located? In your Activity or Fragment. Because right now you are searching in Activity.

Comment: Show your xml file for both your fragment and the activity hat contains it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work - your `findViewByID` looks for the view inside your activity xml but the view (`R.id.bluetooth_switch`) is inside the fragment's xml.
Look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188050/how-to-access-fragments-child-views-inside-fragments-parent-activity) SO answer for code implementation.

Answer (score 0):

"findViewById" returns null when the provided id (in your example, it's called "bluetooth_switch") doesn't exist in the "resource tree" of the current container

Answer (score 0):

I solved it moving these lines of code to my fragment java file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, had called `setId()` on the view for tracking, and so `findViewById` returns null.
Maybe might help someone