# accessing View objects of fragment from its parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know how to get an instance of `fragment` inside an activity from that activity.
but i don't know how to change properties of View objects like `TextView`,Button inside a fragment from activity.
anybody can help, please give an example for how to do that.

Comment: May be it's already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188050/how-to-access-fragments-child-views-inside-fragments-parent-activity) same like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `findViewById()` from your activity. **Once the fragment is attached to the activity and its view is created** all views are part of the view hierarchy ergo you can retrieve references to them from the activity

Comment: I didn't understand what you have said please give me an example.