# I am not being able to access the text view inside my fragment layout from my Activity using the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have tried all the methods mentioned in the following thread
[How to access Fragment's child views inside fragment's parent Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188050/how-to-access-fragments-child-views-inside-fragments-parent-activity) but none of them seem to work for me. Only after trying hard for an hour and a half, I am asking this question.

My **CategoriesFragment**

```
    public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories,container,false);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.cat_text);
            Log.i("Tag",textView.getText().toString());
            return view;
        }

        public TextView getTextView(){
            return textView;
        }

         .

         .

         .

 }
```

I am opening the categories fragment when the user clicks on a bottom navigation view consisting of a categories tab.

My **HomeScreen** Activity

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, CategoriesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

 private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
 private CategoriesFragment categoriesFragment;
 private FrameLayout bottomFrameLayout;
 private TextView textView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
        bottomFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_frame);
        categoriesFragment = new CategoriesFragment();
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
             case R.id.bottom_nav_categories :
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottom_nav_frame,categoriesFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                textView = categoriesFragment.getTextView();
                textView.setText("DONE"); 
        }
        return true;
}
```

This throws a null pointer exception, as it is not being able to get the Text view. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you can pass argument done to fragment and then set the text to textview in fragment itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I will try this out. But, is there no way to do the same inside my activity class?

Answer (score 0):

The `commit()`function does not work synchronously, so your fragment will not be ready directly after the call to it.

Taken from the documentation.

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

Use `commitNow()` as this works synchronously and the fragment is fully brought to the lifycycle state of their host.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitnow for further information

Comment: but using commitNow() will prevent me from adding this to the back stack, something which i want

Answer (score -1):

Why getting textview and setting text from activity when you can pass the string as parameter to the public method of fragment to change text?

Comment: @TaQuangTu  I dont think it is good procedure to expose view of a fragment to an activity and allowing to make changes. It is only a matter of passing a parameter to the fragment. The text value will be changed when views are created.