# unable to setText on TextView. Giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I am setting text on textview but it's giving me NullPointerException

Here's my XML file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activitys.ScoreActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Score Card-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                    android:text="Your Score"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/scoreQTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="100/200"/>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my activity where I am setting text on TextView

```java
public class ScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView scoreQTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
        scoreQTv = findViewById(R.id.scoreQTv);
        //and finded all widgets using findviewByID ...

        scoreQTv.setText("My Score 18");

  }
```

I am unable to set text on my TextViews. How can I set text, and why am I getting this error?

When I check my layout file, I got 2 files with the same name. I think that's why this happens. I have 2 files like this:

1. activity_score.xml
2. activity_score.xml v21 written under the name.

This is my LogCat:

```
021-09-11 13:33:18.729 3897-3897/com.vishal.kaitka.phodo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vishal.kaitka.phodo, PID: 3897
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vishal.kaitka.phodo/com.vishal.kaitka.phodo.Activitys.ScoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.vishal.kaitka.phodo.Activitys.ScoreActivity.onCreate(ScoreActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: cast `scoreQTv` to `TextView`, -> **scoreQTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreQTv);**

Comment: Is `R.layout.activity_score` is the layout that you post in this question?

Comment: @Linh yes I posted that layout

Comment: @mr1554 still getting error

Comment: I think you have to set the Text first, then call findViewById() method.

Comment: @mr1554 still getting same error

Comment: hope this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224285/textview-settext-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In Your Question You have 2 files with same name

1.activity_score.xml

2.activity_score.xml v21

So you can delete that xml layouts and make new activity:

**Create New Activity named `Anything You Want`**

and paste all xml code to that new Activity's xml layout

and all java code to that's new Activity java file

**I thing Maybe it help you!**

Comment: I will try to do that

Comment: I don't know How but it's work! Thank You

Comment: Oh When I check My layout file I got 2 files with the same name I think that's why this happens

Comment: @JamesBond maybe