# App cannot be launched: YourApp has stopped message

Tags: android

Here is the logcat output I am receiving. The app was working fine a few days ago, but suddenly the app cannot be launched in the emulator. I have tried creating new emulators a number of times. Also tried killing the process adb.exe and restarting it, but to no use. Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

```
> 06-18 00:40:53.905: D/AndroidRuntime(898): Shutting down VM 06-18
> 00:40:53.905: W/dalvikvm(898): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> uncaught exception (group=0x41465700) 06-18 00:40:53.925:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-18 00:40:53.925:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 06-18 00:40:53.925:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-18 00:40:53.925:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 06-18 00:40:53.925:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-18 00:40:53.925:
> E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 06-18
> 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
> 06-18 00:40:53.925: E/AndroidRuntime(898):    ... 11 more 06-18
> 00:40:59.568: I/Process(898): Sending signal. PID: 898 SIG: 9 06-18
> 00:48:38.636: D/AndroidRuntime(919): Shutting down VM 06-18
> 00:48:38.636: W/dalvikvm(919): threadid=1: thread exiting with
> uncaught exception (group=0x41465700) 06-18 00:48:38.676:
> E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-18 00:48:38.676:
> E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 06-18 00:48:38.676:
> E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-18 00:48:38.676:
> E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 06-18 00:48:38.676:
> E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-18 00:48:38.676:
> E/AndroidRuntime(919): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 06-18
> 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
> 06-18 00:48:38.676: E/AndroidRuntime(919):    ........... 11 more
```

[EDIT]: Main Activity Code

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: post your `MainActivity` code

Comment: indicate line 32 @ `MainActivity`

Comment: show your code please

Comment: what is line number 32 in your `MainActivity`

Comment: Added MainActivity code

Comment: Is your `button1` belong to your `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: `button1` is null because Button with `button1` id is not exists on `activity_main` layout, instead of that you put your button into `fragment_main`, so put your button to `activity_main` layout or move your code to Fragment class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Comment: Yes, I have added my button to fragment_main? Should I be adding it to activity_main?

Comment: yes @Pranav or you can move your code to Fragment ( i suggest first solution for you )

Comment: Alright, I will go with adding the Button and EditText in activity_main.xml But another question that strikes is why have developer.android.com tutorials asked us to add the Button and EditText in fragment_main and what different are they doing?

Comment: No @Pranav don't change your `activity_main.xml`, Here you have container, If you change it, you code will not work, please follow my answer, just simple changes will made you smooth.

Comment: OK..so going with your answer @Gunaseelan , can you please answer my question in the comments section of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `R.id.button1` should be in your `fragment_main`. So you have to change your `PlaceholderFragment` as like following.

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button button1 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And remove the following code from `onCreate` method

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: When I try this code of yours, it gives an error for getApplicationContext() as "cannot make static reference to the nonstatic method". How to resolve this? @Gunaseelan

Comment: @Pranav I have updated my code. Please change `getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity()`. It will work.

Comment: There are no more errors. But the activity has stopped again and failed to launch.

Comment: @Pranav Did you remove the code from `onCreate` which I have said?

Comment: Yup already Done that.

Comment: Then please tell me what is error you are getting? Otherwise I could not help you.

Comment: Clean your project and try to run again.

Comment: I tried this again by restarting Eclipse and it worked this time! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just one more advice, is it a good practice to declare components in fragment_main and then work in Fragment class or to declare components in main_activity and then work in MainActivity class? @Gunaseelan

Comment: Activities will hold `Fragments`, So you have to do everything in fragments only, See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).