# "Unfortunately, 'App name' has stopped working." : Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am a begginner trying to build android apps.I just copy pasted the code in the Eclipse software.But I dont know what is going wrong here.The application isnt getting opened.Hope my doubts will be cleared.Thanks in advance.

Here is my fragment_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text" />
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button myButton;
EditText myText;
int count=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_text);

    myText.setSingleLine();
    myText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myButton.setText("You hav clicked"+ ++count+ "times.!!!");
            }
        });
```

Here is the logCat:

```
07-03 05:45:46.860: D/AndroidRuntime(991): Shutting down VM.
07-03 05:45:46.860: W/dalvikvm(991): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception        
(group=0xb2a23ba8)07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991): FATAL EXCEPTION:main
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991): Process: com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp,PID:991
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991): java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start
activityComponentInfo{com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp/com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp.
MainActivity}
:java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at   

android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at      
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  
Method)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-03 05:45:46.880: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  ... 11 more
07-03 05:45:52.400: I/Process(991): Sending signal. PID: 991 SIG: 9
07-03 05:52:10.125: D/AndroidRuntime(1302): Shutting down VM
07-03 05:52:10.125: W/dalvikvm(1302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
exception (group=0xb2a23ba8)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Process: com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp, PID:  
1302
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   
activity 
ComponentInfo{com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp/com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-03 05:52:10.135: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     ... 11 more
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.MyButtonApp.mybuttonapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
     </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should change the order like

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 myText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_text);
```

First you need to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and then reference your View.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are initialising wrong layout.Change **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** to **setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);**

then put setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main) **before** findViewById(); like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
myText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `findViewById()` to the fragment `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` after you've inflated the fragment_main layout you posted.

The views you're attempting to find are in the fragment layout and activity `onCreate()` is too early to find them. (Finding activity views before `setContentView()` would be a problem in case the views were in your activity layout.)

See  [NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate) for more.