# listview.setadapter(adapter) causing null pointer exception in oncreate()

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

application crashes on the launch of this activity but the code runs fine if the code to set the adapter is called through the onClick() method upon clicking a button ... 
If the code is used in onCreateview() than onCreate() then static reference cant be made to no static method findViewById()

```
public class DeviceList extends ActionBarActivity {

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdevices);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(pairedDevices.size()>0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices) {
            list.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,    list);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

the xml file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.checkingbluetooth.DeviceList$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="#C0C0C0" 
android:orientation="vertical">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listdevices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

the log is

```
07-09 15:08:07.414: W/dalvikvm(22973): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e6cae0)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.checkingbluetooth/com.example.checkingbluetooth.DeviceList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1239)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at com.example.checkingbluetooth.DeviceList.onCreate(DeviceList.java:48)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
07-09 15:08:07.414: E/AndroidRuntime(22973):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace of your exception

Comment: either `listview` or `pairedDevices` could be null, but I guess, it is `listview`

Comment: Likely listview belongs to the fragment layout

Comment: activity_device_list xml has listdevices ListView element?

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Comment: @Pr38y nops it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException`

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.checkingbluetooth.DeviceList.onCreate(DeviceList.java:48)

My guess in `DeviceList.java:48` is

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listdevices);
```

Reason `listdevices` `ListView` is in your fragment's layout thats why it is *null* put that `ListView` in `activity_device_list`. I think that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

i think your `listview` will be null because your listview should be inside of `PlaceholderFragment` class. please do one thing in add list view inside layout of  `placeholderfragment`  and and then try it will work,thanks;-)

Comment: if i plcae the code inside the placeholderfragment then findviewbyid cant be referenced from inside a static class since it is a non static method

Comment: i know that placeholder is static class but you have to cut your code from line no **12** to **23** from devicelist class and copy it inside placeholder and add list view inside layout of your placeholderframent then it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your :

```
R.id.container
```

If your code passes by the first condition, it will crash. Remove it if you don't use it.