# Whats wrong with my code? Android simple list view example

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating simple listview from string array. i watched many tutorials all are saying the same just 3 lines enough to make it work.I am doing the same but still getting NPE , almost frustrated with this issue. Could not figure out whats went wrong please help me.

My code is here:

**Mainfiest**:

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    String[] days = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, days);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat then...

Comment: you know what,absence of logcat frustrate people at SO,when SOMEONE ask question about NPE or ANR

Comment: what is the line number of NPE ?

Comment: Is your listview in your fragment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error which is not included in the question.

Comment: Check this your **listView1** is belong to your **activity_main layout**.

Comment: i have strongly doubt that you are using wrong XML file.......

So check it first...

Comment: its a common prob with beginners..i have faced it too.. so no worries..

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException accessing views in onCreate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey are you wrong configure code. here you are put listview in fragment xml and write your code in mainactivity class so you have to either remove your fragment xml and Replace your fragment xml code to mainactivity xml and Remove below code

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

from onCreate()

OR

Just Initialize your Listview in OnCreateView of Fragment Class

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView lv;
String[] days = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
            lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GetActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, days);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your showing new fragment in your activity.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

But listview is declared in main activity layout.
So to view your list view just comment above code and see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add items in your "String[] days" to your "adapter" you can use the methods adapter.add or adapter.addAll for adding items to your ArrayAdapter.for more details here is an example of simple listView

http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php