# Error after pressing a button

Tags: android

Code written for getting click event on button

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button pressed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
    });
}
```

This results in `can't launch error`

---

Development Environment 
      Eclipse with ADT

---

+logcat error log

> 08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): FATAL EXCEPTION: mai
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test1/com.example.test1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at com.example.test1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   08-13 16:49:46.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1143):     ... 11 more

---

if iv edited an xml file, it would be this.. otherwise all is generated default

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: post your logcat error over here.

Comment: Are you sure that the id "button1" exists in the XML layout ?

Comment: can you please show your complete onCreate method

Comment: for sure i have the button1... well i dragged in and i didnt changed the code for now...

Comment: there must be one more xml file and one more method for fragment im MainActivity. if Yes thn please share that method too

Comment: what happens if you try `MainActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`? And which line is line 23 in your activity?

Comment: maybe the error is for the 'if statement' in the code, if you don't write that and it generated automatically,then comment it.

Comment: Nahh.. mainactivity.this doesnt work... and i tried deleting toast occoring code and run it, but it still did not load....

Comment: if there is a duplicate, please have link for the location...

Comment: there must be a xml file that is fragment_main.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Comment: if you dont want fragments then you can delete all things related to it and work on activities and extend your mainactivity with Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) 
{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button pressed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
});
```

Comment: sorry.. same error...

Comment: post your logcat error over here